# How do I record from Ardour with Audacity?

Tags: audacity, audio-recording, ardour

Ok I am having this problem with Audacity. I tested a theory and this is what I have discovered. Audacity will record from an outside source, but when I set up Qjackctl and Ardour it stops recording. My guess is it has something to do with Qjackctl, but you need that for Ardour. All I am trying to do is convert a file from WAV to MP3. Thank you all again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [a Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/record_system_sound) on recording system sound on your Ubuntu computer.  You can use this method to change what device Audacity records from.

If all you want to do is convert a file from WAV to MP3, just import it into Audacity and then re-export it, there's no need to play it with one piece of software and attempt to record it, etc.  You could also check out the program `winff`.  It's available in the repos (so `sudo apt install winff`) and gives you an easy to use GUI for converting files.